GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command when running testcase in spring boot 3
I have 2 tables user and token and user can have more tokens in Spring boot 3. The 2 table is following:
user.java
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "full_name")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at", insertable = false)
    private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Token> tokens;
}

token.java
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "token")
public class Token {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String token;

    @Column(name = "expired")
    private boolean expired;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}

When I run test cases, I get the following error although all test cases passed. I tried to resolve it but was not done:
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table token drop foreign key FKe32ek7ixanakfqsdaokm4q9y2" via JDBC [Table 'test.token' doesn't exist]

DemoControllerTest.java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class DemoControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private DemoController demoController;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void demoControllerInitializedCorrectly() {
        assertThat(demoController).isNotNull();
    }

    @Test
    void testReturn200() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/demo")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void testReturnDemoMessage() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/demo")).andExpect(content().string(containsString("API demo is running")));
    }
}

If can, please explain why that error occurs and how to resolve it. Thanks

When I run test cases Can you share your unit test code?

I have updated in post
